# onRequestPermissionsResult returns immediately with denied permission

Tags: android, permissions

My Android app needs to request permission for location services. I do this with:

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{
                            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},
                            REQUEST_CODE_ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION);
```

But immediately after this is called, onRequestPermissionsResult returns immediately with permission denied:

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_CODE_ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION: {

        }
    }
}
```

The permission is listed in the manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COURSE_LOCATION"/>
```

I also cleared the cache to prevent any previous denial the user gave from affecting this.

I am expecting a dialog to pop up requesting the user to grant or deny permission to the location services but it isn't showing.

Comment: I am also having the same problem but i have spelled the permissions correctly. any other reason for this behaviour? @AndroidDev

Comment: We are still waiting for the answer... @AndroidDev

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Change:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COURSE_LOCATION"/>
```

to:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
```

The permission is for "coarse" location data (i.e., not fine-grained), not "course" location data (e.g., where some university class is being held).

Comment: The weird thing is that I came across another SO posting that also indicated a spelling mistake, so I did check the spelling but it still got past me. :-(

Comment: @AndroidDev: It could be worse. You could have spelled it `COERSE`. :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
private int PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION = 100;  
private void checkPermission() {
     if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
             != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
          requestPermissions(newString[{Manfest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},
                  PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION);
      } else {
          doShowLocation();
      }
  }

  @Override
  public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
          int[] grantResults) {
      if (requestCode == PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
              && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
          showContacts();
     }
  }
```

Comment: I'm doing that. I left this out of my posting to keep things simple. But this code is running on the latest version of Marshmallow.

Comment: there are many things to take care and also place super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

Answer (score 0):

One more scenario that onRequestPermissionsResult can return denied permission even before permission dialog appears is when you declared some other permission in android manifest and asking some other permission in run time. Example:
You have declared

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
```

in android manifest file. However you are trying to get

```
Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS
```

in runtime permission. So making the runtime permission to READ_SMS will work without any issues.